# Gridview Header missing when exporting

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am following this guide for exporting data into PDF. [ASP Snippets export selected grid view rows](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-selected-checked-GridView-Rows-to-PDF-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Everything works however whenever I try to print something out the column names/headers are missing.

The **C#** class is basically the same as the aspsnippet link except the database connection string

This how the html code looks like

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" RowStyle-BackColor="White" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="InvoiceID" HeaderText="Invoice ID" ItemStyle-Width="150px" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Illness" HeaderText="Illness" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="MedicineName" HeaderText="Medicine Name" ItemStyle-Width="150px" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
</Columns>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Green" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
```

This is what the result looks like [image: pic]

Comment: that code is converting the data to an html worker. try convert going in debugger and see wether the header property is hitting that variable then take it from there

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, for some reason the custom styles for my gridview were the ones that disabled it